# Error while sending JSON in DELETE ajax request in angular js although it works fine in chrome postman

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, angularjs-http

Iam trying to send JSON in DELETE ajax request in angular js. It gives 500 Internal server error although it works fine in postman.
[Postman Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPTBS.jpg)

#### My code

```
var data = $scope.removeTaskList;
  
var delete_task_url = base_url + "checklist/"+id+"/tasks";
$http
    .delete(delete_task_url, {data:{data}})
    .success(function(data) {
        httpService.get(get_checklist_url,"")
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.status == 200) {
                    console.log("task deleted");
            } else {
                toast('some error occured');
                console.log("some error occured");
            }
        })
    });
```

where delete_task_url is levigo.com/public/dashboard/api/v1/checklist/4/tasks

#### JSON

[image: JSON SENT]

> Error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: There's a subtle difference. In your screenshot from Postman `tasks` is an array of objects, but in your screenshot of the JSON sent from Angular, `tasks` has a child property of `0`. Do you really need the `{data:{data}}` or can you just use `{data: data}`?

Comment: @lex: screen shot of JSON attached is just a parsed view... else sourced view is `{"data":{"tasks":[{"task_name":"new task 1","id":26}]}}` .     Also i tried using `{data: data}` but this removes data from JSON and JSON created then is `{"tasks":[{"task_name":"new task 1","id":26}]}`

Comment: You may need to call JSON.stringify because it looks like your array is getting converted to an object.

Comment: The issue was `Content-Type`. I changed it to `
    $http({method: "DELETE",
            url: delete_task_url, 
            data:{data},
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }})`